# Drawing filled polygon on ARKit Horizontal plane

Tags: ios, swift, polygon, arkit, uibezierpath

How would I draw a filled polygon connecting points touched by user on a detected horizontal plane in ARKit world.

I went on to do this by keeping hit points on an array...

```
let position = SCNVector3.positionFrom(matrix: result.worldTransform)
let sphere = SphereNode(position: position)
nodes.append(position)
```

... and then trying to draw a bezier path

```
let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
bezierPath.lineWidth = 0.1

for index in 0..<nodes.count {

    let node = nodes[index] as SphereNode
    if (index == 0) {

       let point = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(node.position.x), y: CGFloat(node.position.z))
       bezeierPath.move(to: point)


    } else {
       let point = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(node.position.x), y: CGFloat(node.position.z))
        bezeierPath.addLine(to: point)

     }

 }

bezeierPath.close()
bezeierPath.fill()
bezeierPath.stroke()

let shape = SCNShape(path: bezeierPath, extrusionDepth: 0.03)
shape.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
let node = SCNNode.init(geometry: shape)
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

But this doesn't draw the polygon on the correct place. it draw it behind the camera vertically angled.

Comment: have found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

2D geometries like `SCNPlane`, `SCNText` and `SCNShape` are vertical by nature because they work on the xy plane. In your example, you're using the z 3D coordinate as the y 2X coordinate.

Try setting `node.eulerAngles.x` to `-.pi / 2` (if that doesn't work try without the `-`), and your node will be horizontal instead of vertical.

Comment: Thanks, That's make the node horizontal, but still keep it gets drawn behind the camera and above the horizontal plane.